# Second derivative at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
xy\frac{x^{2}-2y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{matrix}\right. $$ Calculate $ f_{xy} (0,0), f_{yx}(0,0) $.

- I found $f_{x}$ and then for $f_{xy}(0,0) $ I took the limit:
  $$f_{xy}(0,0) =\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{f_{x}(0,y)-f_{x}(0,0)}{y-0}$$
  For $ f_{x}(0,0) $ I also took the limit:
  $$f_{x}(0,0) =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}$$
  I got that $f_{x}(0,0) = 0 $ and $f_{x}(0,y) = -2y$ , so $$f_{xy}(0,0) = -2$$
- I did similar things for $f_{yx}(0,0) $ and I got that $$f_{yx}(0,0) = 0 $$

Can I be correct?

Comment: I get $f_{yx}(0,0)=1$ instead of $0$.

Comment: @Ernie060 You are absolutely right! Thanks!